# Asterisk Monitor() does not working when voice playback

Tags: audio, sip, asterisk, pbx

im using asterisk in my application and this is how my extensions.conf looks

```
[default]
exten => _[*#0-9a-zA-Z+].,1,Answer
exten => _[*#0-9a-zA-Z+].,n,Wait(2)
exten => _[*#0-9a-zA-Z+].,n,Monitor(wav,test123,i)
exten => _[*#0-9a-zA-Z+].,n,Dial(SIP/0000FFFF0001,35,L(2000)|A(hello-world))
```

i configured 0000FFFF0001 sip phone and that is also playing an announcement.So there are 2 playbacks from both ends.But when i listen to the test123.wav file it contains only the sound that played from 0000FFFF0001 after the hello-world finished.So basically i don't have the sound part from 0000FFFF0001 announcement when when asterisk playback is there.

Answer (score 0):

You have to check flags in Monitor application - [url to doc](https://wiki.asterisk.org/wiki/display/AST/Application_Monitor)

> i - Skip recording of input stream (disables m option).

So in your case you use `i` flag which disables recording of second side of call. You just have to remove it, then you will receive 2 files, each for one side of call. If you want asterisk to mix them use `m` flag.

Comment: tried it and -in.wav file is empty and -out.wav file is same as described above